# Please suggest why the following test is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

The following method passes tests appropriately:

```
def associate_grid_location
        devices.each do |device|
            if device.grid_location and grid_location_id.nil?
                update_attribute(:grid_location_name,device.grid_location.grid_name)
                update_attribute(:grid_location_id,device.grid_location_id)
                break
            end
        end
    end
```

However if I run the same test logic on a call to this method, it fails to update each cabinets' grid_location_name and grid_location_id:

```
def self.associate_grid_locations
        Cabinet.all.each do |cabinet|
            cabinet.associate_grid_location
        end
    end
```

Please suggest why it may be failing.

Passing test:

```
test "Cabinet associate grid location from device where device has grid location" do
    @cabinet = cabinets(:one)
    @cabinet.grid_location_id = nil
    @device = devices(:one)
    @grid_location = grid_locations(:one)
    @grid_location.grid_name = "test location"
    @device.grid_location = @grid_location
    @cabinet.devices << @device
    @cabinet.associate_grid_location

    assert_equal @grid_location.grid_name, @cabinet.grid_location_name, "Failed: Did not update cabinet grid location"
    assert_equal @device.grid_location.id, @cabinet.grid_location_id, "Failed: Did not update cabinet grid location"
  end
```

Failing test:

```
test "Cabinet associate grid location from device where device has grid location (Called on Cabinet)" do
    @cabinet = cabinets(:one)
    @cabinet.grid_location_id = nil
    @device = devices(:one)
    @grid_location = grid_locations(:one)
    @grid_location.grid_name = "test location"
    @device.grid_location = @grid_location
    @cabinet.devices << @device
    Cabinet.associate_grid_locations

    assert_equal @grid_location.grid_name, @cabinet.grid_location_name, "Failed: Did not update cabinet grid location"
    assert_equal @device.grid_location.id, @cabinet.grid_location_id, "Failed: Did not update cabinet grid location"
  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Cabinet.associate_grid_locations` calls `Cabinet.all`, which instantiates new objects (unless you have identity-map enabled) that are not linked to the objects you have instantiated in your test.  Calling `#reload` on `@cabinet` should make the test pass, assuming there are no other errors.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further?  Where do I call reload?  Right before the call to `Cabinet.associate_grid_locations

`?

Comment: The call to `Cabinet.associate_grid_locations` updates the database, so you'd want to call reload **after** that call such that the object in your test is populated with the updated data.